# Fastest way to get rowSums of multiplication of matrix by a vector in R

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors `v`, `w` and `a`. I want to find out the summation of indicator `(v > w_i)* a_i.`Is there any faster way than following code?

```
v = rnorm(1600)
w = runif(500)
a = rnorm(500)
m = v > rep(w, each = length(v))
dim(m)=c(length(v), length(w))

. system.time({
    m = v > rep(w, each = length(v))
    dim(m)=c(length(v), length(w))
    rowSums(m %*% diag(a))
  })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.03    0.00    0.04
```

Comment: What are you going to do with your extra 4 seconds? I think this is more suited to code review. Perhaps if you described what you wanted (not just have a wall of code).

Comment: summation of indicator (v > w_i)* a_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a non-vectorized solution will be faster than setting up a giant sparse matrix like you have done with `diag`.

```
system.time(
  res<-sapply(v,function(v1)sum(a[v1>w]))
) 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.032   0.000   0.031

system.time({
  m = v > rep(w, each = length(v))
  dim(m)=c(length(v), length(w))
  res<-rowSums(m %*% diag(a))
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.364   0.000   0.362
```

But, if you wanted to get fancy, you could do something like this:

```
fancy<-function(){
  order.w<-order(w)
  cumsum.a<-c(0,cumsum(a[order.w]))
  cumsum.a[findInterval(v,c(-Inf,w[order.w]))]
}
system.time(res2<-fancy())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0       0       0 
all.equal(res,res2)
# TRUE
```